# I left money in my JP Bank account when I permanently departed Japan. What are my options for accessing it?

Tags: banking, japan

I previously resided in Japan, but I left the country two years ago and no longer have residence status. What are my options for accessing the money I left in my Japan Post Bank account there?

More info:

- I did not sign up for internet banking with JP Bank, and my account
  is not linked to any money transfer services or cards that can be
  used overseas.
- I do not have my My Number certificate or card in my possession, only
  the number itself.
- I do not have any connections currently in Japan whom I am comfortable
  asking to handle a financial issue.

Comment: Return to Japan as a visitor and go to the relevant branch to request to access the money in person?

Answer (score 5):

From personal experience, it is **effectively impossible** to access a Japanese bank account from overseas if you did not set up Internet banking or an internationally networked credit/debit card before you left.  This is the case even if you have a trusted intermediary (relative etc) to file paperwork on your behalf.

Fintech services etc will not help here, because even though they might help you get the money out of the country, you still need to transfer money domestically from your account to their local holding account.

Realistically speaking, you'll need to either return to Japan in person to withdraw the money, or entrust your ATM card and its PIN code to somebody physically in Japan (living or visiting) who can do it for you.

Comment: how about getting it through japanese embassy?

Comment: @user0193 The banking arrangements of a foreign citizen with a Japanese bank are of absolutely no interest to the Japanese Embassy.